# R loop to perform the same task on multiple Rasters?

Tags: r, raster, rgdal

I am looking to create a loop to perform the same task on 12 raster's in a folder, I've done the said task for 1 raster. The task involves counting the cell (that have either a class of 1 2 3 or 4) and then calculating the area of each class. Then I need to save the area values in a new data frame for further analysis and visualisation.

I need 1 raster saved as baseline (which is the one in my example) and the rest title Sub_A, Sub_B and so on till Sub_K.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

wd<- ('E:/Subs')
setwd(wd)


zuk1<- raster("E:/Subs/ZUK1_MAX.tif")
zuk1
zuk1<- setMinMax(zuk1)
zuk1[zuk1 == 0]<- NA

plot(zuk1, main='Baseline Hazard')

#count for pixel per class
hazard_fr<- freq(zuk1, useNA="no")
hazard_fr
resclass<- res(zuk1)
area_km2<- hazard_fr[,"count"] * prod(resclass) * 1e-06
df_class_area<- data.frame(Hazard = (c("Low", "Moderate", "Significant", "Extreme")))
df_class_area
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of getting the desired output. It is very similar to Jeremy's answer; but using `lapply`.

```
# List files which names start with zuk and end with .tif
zuk_files <- list.files(pattern = glob2rx("zuk*.tif"))

# The loop
resuls <- lapply(zuk_files, function(x){
  zuk1 <- raster(x)
  zuk1 <- setMinMax(zuk1)
  zuk1[zuk1 == 0] <- NA
  hazard_fr <- freq(zuk1, useNA="no")
  resclass <- res(zuk1)
  hazard_fr[,"count"] * prod(resclass) * 1e-06
})
```

Comment: `zuk1 <- setMinMax(zuk1)` can be omitted; and `zuk1[zuk1 == 0] <- NA`  is better written as `zuk1 <- reclassify(zuk1, cbind(0, NA))`

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a small example data, it will be easier for others to help you. I know that for this case, you may not be able to provide them, as tiff files are generally big in size.

Anyway, you can try this:

```
# list all tiff files in your directory 
zuk_files <- list.files(pattern = "*.tif")  

# you can also try to be more specific like:
 zuk_files <- list.files(pattern = "ZUK.*_MAX.tif")  

# then apply the same operations for all of the target files

# first create a list for whatever you want to loop over
zuk <- list()
hazard_fr <- list()
resclass <- list()
area_km2 <- list()
df_class_area <- list()

# now do the same things for all items in the list
for (i in 1:length(zuk_files)){
  zuk[[i]] <- raster(zuk_files[[i]])
  zuk[[i]] <- setMinMax(zuk[[i]])
  zuk[[i]][zuk[[i]] == 0] <- NA
  hazard_fr[[i]] <- freq(zuk[[i]],useNA="no")
  resclass[[i]] <- res(zuk[[i]])
  area_km2[[i]] <- hazard_fr[[i]][,"count"] * prod(resclass[[i]]) * 1e-06
  df_class_area[[i]] <- data.frame(Hazard = (c("Low", "Moderate", "Significant", "Extreme")))
}

# then all the data are stored in the list, you can acess them using the index like:
zuk[[1]]

# or save out your target results like:
zuk_1 <- zuk[[1]]
```

But I am not sure if you have made a mistake in

```
df_class_area <- data.frame(Hazard = (c("Low", "Moderate", "Significant", "Extreme")))
```

I am not sure this line does what you expect, anyway, you can learn from the examples above to write the loop for that df_class_area, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for this, yes my tif files are very large but they all have the same extent, projection etc.

Comment: When trying out the above code, the list are empty even after the loop.

Comment: @AmrieSingh I do not know what has caused the issue, but a general practice to debug is to run the codes line by line. In the for loop, first try to only include one operation, like `` zuk[[i]] <- raster(zuk_files[[i]])``. Then you can check the results for that step, if everything is fine, add the next operation in the loop and run again until you see which step caused the problem.

Comment: Hello, it wasnt an error it just took R some time to deal with my data cause they are so large.  The only issue now is that  its not removing the null values from all raster's just one.